# python style question around reading small files

Tags: python, coding-style, idioms

What is the most pythonic way to read in a named file, strip lines that are either empty, contain only spaces, or have # as a first character, and then process remaining lines?  Assume it all fits easily in memory.

Note: it's not tough to do this -- what I'm asking is for the most pythonic way.  I've been writing a lot of Ruby and Java and have lost my feel.

Here's a strawman:

```
file_lines = [line.strip() for line in open(config_file, 'r').readlines() if len(line.strip()) > 0]
for line in file_lines:
  if line[0] == '#':
    continue
  # Do whatever with line here.
```

I'm interested in concision, but not at the cost of becoming hard to read.

Comment: So lines with leading/trailing spaces should be stripped?

Comment: Just spaces, or any whitespace?

Comment: @Kevin, your text doesn't quite match your code.  You say you'll strip lines with "#" as the first character (BTW, is that pre- or post-stripping?) but you don't say you'll discard those lines... but your example code does skip them.

Comment: +1 for the use of "concision."  Didn't think it was a real word until I looked it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lines = [r for r in open(thefile) if not r.isspace() and r[0] != '#']
```

The `.isspace()` method of strings is by far the best way to test if a string is entirely whitespace -- no need for contortions such as `len(r.strip()) == 0` (ech;-).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about isspace.

Comment: `"".isspace()` returns False, but `r` will always have at least a newline in it

Comment: @gnibbler, be careful with it though... works fine here because the lines are all newline-terminated (or non-empty, which the last line will be even if it's not properly terminated).  If they're not, this won't work as `isspace()` returns `False` for empty strings.

Comment: Yep, in a different situation (where empty strings might be a possibility -- not applicable to the actual problem) you might have to use `r and not r.isspace()` to exclude both empty and all-whitespace strings. Not applicable to _this_ question though;-).

Answer (score 5):

Generators are perfect for tasks like this. They are readable, maintain perfect separation of concerns, and efficient in memory-use and time.

```
def RemoveComments(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip().startswith('#'):
            yield line

def RemoveBlankLines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip():
            yield line
```

Now applying these to your file:

```
filehandle = open('myfile', 'r')
for line in RemoveComments(RemoveBlankLines(filehandle)):
    Process(line)
```

In this case, it's pretty clear that the two generators can be merged into a single one, but I left them separate to demonstrate their composability.

Comment: Generator expressions would be much more Pythonic, especially since the question specifically asks for concision.

Comment: It's clear, simple, easy to tell what it does and easy to test.

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in open("file"):
    sline=line.strip()
    if sline and not sline[0]=="#" :
       print line.strip()
```

output

```
$ cat file
one
#
  #

two

three
$ ./python.py
one
two
three
```

Comment: Any reason you use `not foo == bar` instead of `foo != bar` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
processed = [process(line.strip())
             for line in open(config_file, 'r')
             if line.strip() and not line.strip().startswith('#')]
```

The only ugliness I see here is all the repeated stripping. Getting rid of it complicates the function a bit:

```
processed = [process(line)
             for line in (line.strip() for line in open(config_file, 'r'))
             if line and not line.startswith('#')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This matches the description, ie

> strip lines that are either empty,
>   contain only spaces, or have # as a
>   first character, and then process
>   remaining lines

So lines that start or end in spaces are passed through unfettered.

```
with open("config_file","r") as fp:
    data = (line for line in fp if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#"))
    for item in data:
        print repr(item)
```

Comment: You need to strip `line` twice in the generator - the return and the `startswith` check. Props for using `with` though.

Comment: @Max, that's not actually the case, if you read the requirements strictly.  He said "or have # as first character" (i.e. not first non-blank).  He might be happier with the latter interpretation, but gnibbler's answer is correct.

Comment: Right. I went off the code in the question, which does strip in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I like Paul Hankin's thinking, but I'd do it differently:

```
from itertools import ifilter, ifilterfalse, imap

with open(r'c:\temp\testfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    s1 = ifilterfalse(str.isspace, f)
    s2 = ifilter(lambda x: not x.startswith('#'), s1)
    s3 = imap(str.rstrip, s2)
    print "\n".join(s3)
```

I'd probably only do it this way instead of using some of the more obvious approaches suggested here if I were concerned about memory usage.  And I might define an `iscomment` function to eliminate the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The file is small, so performance is not really an issue.  I will go for clarity than conciseness:

```
fp = open('file.txt')
for line in fp:
    line = line.strip()
    if line and not line.startswith('#'):
        # process
fp.close()
```

If you want, you can wrap this in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Using slightly newer idioms (or with Python 2.5 `from __future__ import with`) you could do this, which has the advantage of cleaning up safely yet is quite concise.

```
with file('file.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line[0] == '#':
            continue

        # rest of processing here
```

Note that stripping the line first means the check for "#" will actually reject lines with that as the *first non-blank*, not merely "as first character".  Easy enough to modify if you're strict about that.